# Combining two collections backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am making a statistical app for basketball, there is a collection of players and their attributes.

```
players = new App.Collections.PlayersList(
    [
        {   
            name: 'McGee',
            points: '14'
        },
        {
            name: 'Joe E',
            points: '21'
        },
        {
            name: 'Mike',
            points: '8'
        }
    ]
);
```

Then I have a list of teams

```
teams = new App.Collections.TeamsList(
    [
        {   
            team: 'Green', //Accidentally used uppercase, will change that, just didnt want to confuse you because it's uppercase in the console.log picture below
        },
        {
            team: 'Blue',
        }
    ]
);
```

I followed this [How to place a collection within a model in Backbone.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994548/how-to-place-a-collection-within-a-model-in-backbone-js)
and added into my teams model.

```
App.Models.Team = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // Default attributes for the player item.
    initialize: function() {
        // assuming Players a collection of players
        console.log(this.set('players', new App.Collections.PlayersList));
    }

});
```

Inside the console I see both models, but players is empty.

[image]

This is not some big complex issue, I am just a noob and have no idea how to approach :)

I am trying to get a result like this. Actually this may be tough attaching a player to a team, how would I say these players are on this team?

```
<div class="green">
    <li data-player="McGee">Name: McGee, Points: 14</li>
    <li data-player="Joe">Name: Joe E, Points: 21</li>
    <li data-player="Mike">Name: Mike, Points: 8</li>
</div>

// Havent created players for this yet, but you get it
<div class="blue">
    <li class="">Name: McGee, Points: 14</li>
    <li class="">Name: Joe E, Points: 21</li>
    <li class="">Name: Mike, Points: 8</li>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** *So I am trying something out, this isnt ideal but so far its working, hopefully I can get an answer, I mean is this ideal or I am sure there is a better way to do this, I am here to learn.*

```
window.greenTeam = new App.Collections.PlayersList(
    [
        {   
            team: 'green',
            name: 'McGee',
            points: '14'
        },
        {
            team: 'green',
            name: 'Joe E',
            points: '21'
        },
        {
            team: 'green',
            name: 'Mike',
            points: '8'
        }
    ]
);

window.blueTeam = new App.Collections.PlayersList(
    [
        {   
            team: 'blue',
            name: 'Steve',
            points: '14'
        },
        {
            team: 'blue',
            name: 'Eli',
            points: '21'
        },
        {
            team: 'blue',
            name: 'John',
            points: '8'
        }
    ]
);

window.orangeTeam = new App.Collections.PlayersList(
    [
        {   
            team: 'orange',
            name: 'Kobe',
            points: '14'
        },
        {
            team: 'orange',
            name: 'Lebron',
            points: '21'
        },
        {
            team: 'orange',
            name: 'Melo',
            points: '8'
        }
    ]
);


//Create new instaces to initialize each view

// New *App.Views.Player* instance, need to instantiate to set the model in the view.
// ------------
//window.playersView = new App.Views.Players({ collection: players });

window.greenTeamView = new App.Views.Players({ collection: greenTeam });
window.blueTeamView = new App.Views.Players({ collection: blueTeam });
window.orangeTeamView = new App.Views.Players({ collection: orangeTeam });
```

**Edit:** Okay this is **NOT** ideal lol but it works, take a look at my full code, I know I am throwing out a lot of words here but, if you saw this code how would you simplify it, points to whomever solves this puzzle :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="green"></div>

    <div class="blue"></div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js"></script>

    <!-- Templates -->
    <script type="text/template" id="player-template">
        <div class="">Name: <%= name %> - Points: <%= points %><button class="btn"></button></div>
    </script>

<script>
$(function(){

    //Name spacing
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Router: {}
    };


/*** OUR MODEL OF A PLAYER... PLAYER MODEL then SINGLE PLAYER VIEW ***/

    // Player Model
    // ----------

    // Our **Player** model has `name`, `points`, and `rebounds` attributes.
    window.App.Models.GreenPlayer = Backbone.Model.extend({
        // Default attributes for the player item.
        defaults: {
            team: "Green",
            name: "Michael",
            points: 10,
            rebounds: 9
        }

    });

    window.App.Models.BluePlayer = Backbone.Model.extend({
        // Default attributes for the player item.
        defaults: {
            team: "Blue",
            name: "Michael",
            points: 10,
            rebounds: 9
        }

    });

    // Single player view
    // ---------------

    // This is a view of how a player should look.
    window.App.Views.GreenPlayer = Backbone.View.extend({

        //el is a list tag.
        tagName:  "li",

        // Cache the template function for a single item.
        template: _.template($('#player-template').html()),

        events: {
            'click .btn': 'mikeAlert'
        },

        mikeAlert: function() {
           alert('get food');
        },

        // Re-render the titles of the todo item.
        render: function() {
          this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
          this.$el.addClass( this.model.get('name') );
          var test = this.model.get('name');
          return this;
        }

    });

    // This is a view of how a player should look.
    window.App.Views.BluePlayer = Backbone.View.extend({

        //el is a list tag.
        tagName:  "li",

        // Cache the template function for a single item.
        template: _.template($('#player-template').html()),

        events: {
            'click .btn': 'mikeAlert'
        },

        mikeAlert: function() {
           alert('get food');
        },

        // Re-render the titles of the todo item.
        render: function() {
          this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
          this.$el.addClass( this.model.get('name') );
          var test = this.model.get('name');
          return this;
        }

    });


/*** END PLAYER MODEL SETUP ***/



/*** OUR PLAYERS COLLECTION... PLAYERS COLLECTION then PLAYERS COLLECTION VIEW ***/

    // Players Collection
    // ---------------

    // We connect the players collection to the player model
    // The collection of players is backed by *localStorage* instead of a remote
    // server.
    window.App.Collections.GreenPlayersList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        // Reference to this collection's model.
        model: App.Models.GreenPlayer

        // Save all of the player items under the `"players-backbone"` namespace.
        //localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("players-backbone"),

    });

    window.App.Collections.BluePlayersList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        // Reference to this collection's model.
        model: App.Models.BluePlayer

        // Save all of the player items under the `"players-backbone"` namespace.
        //localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("players-backbone"),

    });


    // Players Collection View
    // ---------------

    // Display a list of all player*s* here.
    window.App.Views.GreenPlayers = Backbone.View.extend({
        // Instead of generating a new element, bind to the existing skeleton of
        // the App already present in the HTML.
        el: $(".app"),

        initialize: function() {
            this.render();
        },

        render: function() {
            this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
            return this;
        },

        addOne: function(model) {

            //Create a new child view
            var greenplayer = new App.Views.GreenPlayer({ model: model });
            $('.green').append( greenplayer.render().el );

        }

    });

    window.App.Views.BluePlayers = Backbone.View.extend({
        // Instead of generating a new element, bind to the existing skeleton of
        // the App already present in the HTML.
        el: $(".app"),

        initialize: function() {
            this.render();
        },

        render: function() {
            this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
            return this;
        },

        addOne: function(model) {

            //Create a new child view
            var blueplayer = new App.Views.BluePlayer({ model: model });
            $('.blue').append( blueplayer.render().el );

        }

    });


/*** END PLAYER*S* COLLECTION SETUP ***/


    // Dummy Collection, new instance of *App.Collections.PlayersList* 
    // ---------------
    window.greenTeam = new App.Collections.GreenPlayersList(
        [
            {   
                team: 'green',
                name: 'McGee',
                points: '14'
            },
            {
                team: 'green',
                name: 'Joe E',
                points: '21'
            },
            {
                team: 'green',
                name: 'Mike',
                points: '8'
            }
        ]
    );

    window.blueTeam = new App.Collections.BluePlayersList(
        [
            {   
                team: 'blue',
                name: 'Steve',
                points: '14'
            },
            {
                team: 'blue',
                name: 'Eli',
                points: '21'
            },
            {
                team: 'blue',
                name: 'John',
                points: '8'
            }
        ]
    );


    //Create new instaces to initialize each view

    // New *App.Views.Player* instance, need to instantiate to set the model in the view.
    // ------------
    //window.playersView = new App.Views.Players({ collection: players });

    window.greenTeamView = new App.Views.GreenPlayers({ collection: greenTeam });
    window.blueTeamView = new App.Views.BluePlayers({ collection: blueTeam });
    //window.orangeTeamView = new App.Views.Players({ collection: orangeTeam });


});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this make sense? If there is another approach id like to hear..

Comment: Is this making sense to anyone, I am just trying to associate a player to a team, but I need to wrap the list of players inside a team view.. End result should look like the HTML in the post above.

Answer (score 2):

In your case there can be many teams (green, blue, etc) each team can have many players. One approach would be to have two different models `Team` and `Player` and then have `one-to-many` relationship from `Team -> Player`. Finally create a `Collection` of `Team`. Have a look at [Backbone Associations](http://dhruvaray.github.io/backbone-associations/index.html) for managing relationships. Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay I will take a look thanks, I literally picked up backbone 3 days ago and I am a noobie in OOP, so instantiating and all that stuff is  new, but I am hanging in there I hope this makes clear sense and can help organize my code :) So far one-to-many relationships sounds cool, I hope I can apply it to my project.

Comment: I did come across this before I had to 1+ you for posting this because I need to man up and just go ahead and learn how to use this. It looked like a lot of work at first, but ill man up lol.

Comment: Is there anyway you can provide a rough simple example, Ill give you points, I just don't quite get the documentation 100%...